# Sort 2d array rows in ascending order of their first elements in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I need to sort 2d array rows in ascending order of their first elements, like in example

> {{5,7,6},{2,9,6},{4,8,1}} --> {{2,9,6},{4,8,1},{5,7,6}}

I can find max element in row, but i don't now how to sort the rows.

```
public double[] maxInRow(double[,] n) 
 { 
    double[] result = new double[n.GetLength(0)]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n.GetLength(0); i++) 
    { 
        double max = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n.GetLength(1); j++) 
        { 
        if (max < n[i,j]) 
        { 
            max = n[i,j];
        } 
        } 
    result[i] = max; 
    } 
return result; 
}
```

Can you advice something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use a `List<>` you could do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4875763/1156119

Comment: You want to sort it inplace?

Comment: Do you want to sort only by the first item in each row? How would you want to sort `{{1,1,3},{1,1,1},{1,1,2}}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly with that sintax you are missing the power of `linq` wich is one of the best components of `.Net framework` you can try this instead

```
double[][] x = new double[2][];
x[0] = new double[] { 5, 2, 5 };
x[1] = new double[] { 6, 8, 3 };
x[2] = new double[] { 8, 3, 6 };

var sortedByFisrtVal =  x.OrderBy(y => y[0]);
var sortedBySecondVal = x.OrderBy(y => y[1]);

//trying to guess maybe this is better
var sorted =  x.OrderBy(y => y[0]).ThenBy(y => y[1]).ThenBy(y => y[2]);
```

Comment: The simplest and efficient method. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If performance is not critical then you can convert your 2D array into array of rows, sort them via `OrderBy` from linq providing the Max as the criteria and then convert the result back to 2D array:

```
        private static T[][] Convert<T>(T[,] source, int firstDim, int secondDim)
        {
            T[][] result = new T[firstDim][];
            for (int i = 0; i < firstDim; i++)
            {
                T[] temp = new T[secondDim];    
                for (int j = 0; j < secondDim; j++)
                {
                    temp[j] = source[i, j];
                }

                result[i] = temp;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static T[,] ConvertBack<T>(T[][] source, int firstDim, int secondDim)
        {
            var result = new T[firstDim, secondDim];
            for (int i = 0; i < firstDim; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < secondDim; j++)
                {    
                    result[i, j] = source[i][j];
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        // usage sample
        double[,] array = { { 5, 7, 6 }, { 2, 9, 6 }, { 4, 8, 1 } };
        int firstDim = array.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
        int secondDim = array.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
        double[][] jagged = Convert(array, firstDim, secondDim);

        // actual sort is done here!
        double[][] sorted = jagged.OrderByDescending(row => row.Max()).ToArray();

        double[,] result = ConvertBack(sorted, firstDim, secondDim);
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need any extra methods. just implement `Sort` method for 2d array as above.

This Sort algorithm is as same as Sort algorithm for 1D array except that you also need third loop to swap elements of row.

```
public static void Sort(double[,] n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            if (n[i, 0] > n[j, 0]) // sort by ascending by first index of each row
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < n.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    var temp = n[i, k];
                    n[i, k] = n[j, k];
                    n[j, k] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can call it like this.

```
Sort(your2dArray);
```

Note that algorithm can become very slow of course as noted by Alexei Levenkov. So use it if the performance is not important here.

If you use [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) instead of 2D array you can make things much faster. Also linq supports 1D array (thus jagged arrays too) which implements IEnumerable and you can use quick sort using `OrderBy`.

Comment: Note that this is insanely inefficient (very slow sort + copying whole rows ...)

Comment: Algoritm is good. The performance doesn't matter for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

2d arrays are not for sorting, but anyway, here is how you can do that

```
public static class MyAlgorithms
{
    public static void SortByFirstColumn<T>(this T[,] array, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        // Indirect sorting
        var sortIndex = new int[array.GetLength(0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < sortIndex.Length; i++)
            sortIndex[i] = i;
        if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        Array.Sort(sortIndex, (a, b) => comparer.Compare(array[a, 0], array[b, 0]));
        // Reorder the array using "in situ" algorithm
        var temp = new T[array.GetLength(1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < sortIndex.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sortIndex[i] == i) continue;
            for (int c = 0; c < temp.Length; c++)
                temp[c] = array[i, c];
            int j = i;
            while (true)
            {
                int k = sortIndex[j];
                sortIndex[j] = j;
                if (k == i) break;
                for (int c = 0; c < temp.Length; c++)
                    array[j, c] = array[k, c];
                j = k;
            }
            for (int c = 0; c < temp.Length; c++)
                array[j, c] = temp[c];
        }
    }
}
```

and use it as follows

```
double[,] data = { { 5, 7, 6 }, { 2, 9, 6 }, { 4, 8, 1 } };
data.SortByFirstColumn();
```

This implementation doesn't suffer performance. For more explanation how it works and some additional options, see my answer to [How can I sort a large 2d array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338430/how-can-i-sort-a-large-2d-array-c-sharp/33341939#33341939)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by first column, then by second, then by third and so on for all columns, you can to this:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = new double[,] {{5,7,6},{2,9,6},{2,5,6},{4,8,1}};

    Sort(input);
    // Input is now:
    // {{2,5,6},{2,9,6},{4,8,1},{5,7,6}}
}

public T[,] Sort<T>(T[,] data) where T : IComparable
{
    // Transform to array of arrays.
    var rows = new T[data.GetLength(0)][];
    for (var i = 0; i< data.GetLength(0); ++i)
    {
        rows[i] = new T[data.GetLength(1)];
        for (var j = 0; j < data.GetLength(1); ++j)
            rows[i][j] = data[i, j];
    }

    // Sort rows using a custom array comparer.
    Array.Sort(rows, new ArrayComparer<T>());

    // Write data back to input array.
    for (var i = 0; i< data.GetLength(0); ++i)
        for (var j = 0; j < data.GetLength(1); ++j)
            data[i, j] = rows[i][j];

    return data;
}

public class ArrayComparer<T> : IComparer<T[]> where T : IComparable
{
    public int Compare(T[] x, T[] y)
    {
        var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

        // Compare elements as long as they're different.
        for(var i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
        {
            var compareResult = comparer.Compare(x[i], y[i]);
            if (compareResult != 0) return compareResult;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.Sort(double, (a,b)=>{return a[0]-b[0];});
```