# Change 2d array bubble sort to counting sort

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, counting-sort

The following code sorts rows by the first element using bubble method.
I can't change it to counting sort.

```
public void SortStack(double[,] n)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < n.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
   {
       for (int j = i; j < n.GetLength(0); j++)
       {
           if (n[i, 0] > n[j, 0]) 
           {
               for (int k = 0; k < n.GetLength(1); k++)
               {
                   var temp = n[i, k];
                   n[i, k] = n[j, k];
                   n[j, k] = temp;
               }
           }
        }
   }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried to implement a counting sort? Have you looked at the various code samples available online?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution for 1d array, but I need to sort 2d array rows. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Counting_sort#C.23

Comment: Counting sort is not applicable for `double`s. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741875/sort-2d-array-rows-in-ascending-order-of-their-first-elements-in-c-sharp/33742498#33742498 for how you can effectively sort a 2d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do bubble sort based on first element of each row. you should do counting sort like that too. so you just need to count first item of each row.

```
private static int[,] CountingSort2D(int[,] arr)
{
    // find the max number by first item of each row
    int max = arr[0, 0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i, 0] > max) max = arr[i, 0]; 
    }

    // we want to get count of first items of each row. thus we need 1d array.
    int[] counts = new int[max + 1]; 

    // do the counting. again on first index of each row
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        counts[arr[i, 0]]++; 
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < counts.Length; i++)
    {
        counts[i] += counts[i - 1];
    }

    // result is sorted array
    int[,] result = new int[arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1)];

    for (int i = arr.GetLength(0) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        counts[arr[i, 0]]--;

        // now we need to copy columns too. thus we need another loop
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            result[counts[arr[i, 0]], j] = arr[i, j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is the test.

```
static void Main()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[,] arr = new int[3,3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            arr[i, j] = rand.Next(0, 100);
        }
    }

    int[,] newarr = CountingSort2D(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ,");
        }
        Console.Write("} ,");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < newarr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < newarr.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(newarr[i, j] + " ,");
        }
        Console.Write("} ,");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Example Output:

```
{ 49,66,8 },{ 33,39,64 },{ 65,52,76 } // Original array
{ 33,39,64 },{ 49,66,8 },{ 65,52,76 } // Sorted array
```